# PYTHON How to open new console and do print strings on that window in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, console

how to open new console and do print strings on that window in python

I want is i have a script , i want to open a new window after it gets started on that windows i want to print strings like Logs basically like the following:

```
[INFO] A() is Running
[WARNING] A() Is Running SO BAD
[FINISHED] A() IS Done
```

WOuld be helpfull if the question is anwered

Answer (score 0):

try to write extra program for handling args to logs. but you will need to execute new python instance from OS using cmd/bash script